# Flask Python How to pass input from textbox to POST request?

Tags: python, flask

I have a python function that converts an input string on a POST request.

```
@app.route('/api/convert', methods=['POST'])
def add_copyright():
    if not request.json or not 'input' in request.json:
        abort(400)
    else:
        userinput = request.json['input']
        dict = ['Oracle', 'oracle', 'Google', 'google', 'Microsoft', 'microsoft', 'Amazon', 'amazon']
        for company in dict:
            userinput = userinput.replace(company, company + '©')
    return jsonify(userinput)
```

Instead of passing a JSON, I'd like to have userinput. I would like to render a template which has a textbox and pass this input to the POST request. Something like this

```
@app.route('/api/convert', methods=['POST'])
def add_copyright():
    userinput = userinput.replace(company, company + '©')
    return render_template('convert.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

use an html form on the front-end with the action being your API endpoint and the method being POST, then on the back-end instead of using:

```
request.json
```

use:

```
request.form[<form input name here>]
```